# MongoDB filter when two fields equal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

Does anyone who knows how to filter data and only keep those history_doc.data.objectId equals _id?

I have tried so many methods but none of them works

```json
{'history_doc.data.objectId': {$eq: '$_id'}}
```

```json
{'history_doc.data.objectId': {$eq: {$toString: '$_id'}}}
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$expr` and `$eq` with `$toObjectId` into aggregation query like this:

```js
.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        "$_id",
        {
          "$toObjectId": "$history_doc.data.objectId"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CjhluqsLcXW).

Comment: hI, thank you so much, but it doesn't work when _id is ObjectId

Comment: I didn't realize it is comparing string and ObjectId. I've updated the answer using `$toObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Aggregation Framework:

- `$match` - to filter documents based on some custom criteria
- `$eq` and `$toString` - To check it `_id` and `history_doc.data.objectId` are the same.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$toString": "$_id"
          },
          "$history_doc.data.objectId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bzWVzLNArE2)